# When my timer ticks.... .NET Memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have a .NET System.Threading.Timer timer that ticks every 60 seconds and introduces a memory leak on each tick.

On each tick of the timer, the code allocates an IDisposable object (called SocketsMessageConnector)...but I do dispose it correctly.

I ran .NET Memory Profiler and every 60 seconds I see a new instance of my SocketsMessageConnector class lingering in memory (so after 15 minutes, I have 15 instances). The memory profiler verifies that the instance is in fact disposed, but it shows the instance rooted by a TimerCallback, which is rooted by a _TimerCallback, which is rooted by a GCHandle...

What's up here? Why is the TimerCallback holding on to the new instance created on every timer tick?

PS. The profiler forces 2 GCs before taking a snapshot, so I know it IS in fact a leak and not just an optimization by the GC.

Comment: Can you post some code for us to look at?

Comment: I read the question and thought "As my timer gently leaks"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because it's been disposed, doesn't mean that it's been Garbage Collected yet.

Try changing your timer to run twice a second, and then let it run for 10 minutes. Now check how many of your class objects are still "lingering in memory". If you truely have a memory leak, you'll have 1200 objects. But if Garbage Collection has jumped in, you'll have considerably less - perhaps under 100.

Comment: The profiler forces two garbage collections, which I would have thought would be sufficient for cleaning up non-referenced instances...but anyway, I've seen it get up to 150 instances. I'll make the timer smaller and try also...

Comment: Well it's very strange...I changed the interval to run every 100ms...and once the memory got up above 200MB, it started to GC correctly and old instances started going away...

Comment: Remember, collection doesnt necessarily actually occur until the GC decides it is a good time. Also, memory handed to your app by the os wont necessarily be handed back straight away once the CLR no longer needs it. Memory allocation is quite complicated. Look at Process Explorer and watch Mark Russinovich explain all the different memory columns and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Its a good idea to try to produce an OutOfMemory exception before assuming you have a real memory leak on your hands.