# Scheduling without use of timer class in c#

Tags: c#, timer, scheduled-tasks

I need a suggestion. How to do scheduling in C# without using a Timer class, as it takes memory. Although it is not an issue if Timer is used in an efficient manner, I am in need of a long-term scheduling process. Please share your suggestions for scheduling without use of timers.

Comment: _"without using timer class as it takes memory"_ - pretty sure most things you do _takes memory_

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer about what you mean by "as it takes memory" and why you think you can't use timers in an efficient manner.

Comment: "as it takes memory"- anything that you use will add some memory footprint.

Comment: Consider using Windows Scheduler. Add your exe in schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something basic like this:

```
public class TimeSchedule
{
    private bool hasRun;
    private DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(2015,5,26);

    private void Schedule()
    {
        while (!hasRun)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Date < targetDate)
            {
                //Do something
                hasRun = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Schedule);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything will use memory.

If you just want to delay something  for x you can just sleep but this would be a bad pattern for most usages but for a simple console type app that you want to pause and do something in x mins its going to be fine. If you are in a async code you can also use

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

If you wish to run something at a certain time of day then as said in the comments a windows scheduled task maybe better. Eg don't have a service that just does X() at say 11:11AM .

also, read this [C# Timer and memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465742/c-sharp-timer-and-memory-leak) and [When my timer ticks.... .NET Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034355/when-my-timer-ticks-net-memory-leak) (they both boil down to non issues)